# Apply Jquery Function in click event of Link button (in code behind)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

this is another question that I want to know that how to apply any jQuery function on `onclick()` event of `Linkbutton`.

I have a one `Linkbutton` and I want to set below jQuery function when linkbutton is clicked.

```
<önclick="TINY.box.show({
    iframe:'User_News.aspx',
    boxid:'frameless',
    width:250,
    height:250,
    fixed:false,
    maskid:'bluemask',
    maskopacity:40,
    closejs:function(){closeJS()}
})"
style="color: #0000FF; font-size: medium; height: 28px;"
id="l1" 
runat="server">
```

This function gives me a popup message. So how to get this popup when linkbutton is clicked?

Comment: That doesn't even look like a valid tag, are you sure your code does anything?

Comment: i have same like <li onclick="TINY.box.show({iframe:'User_News.aspx',boxid:'frameless',width:250,height:250,fixed:false,maskid:'bluemask',maskopacity:40,closejs:function(){closeJS()}})" 
                                       style="color: #0000FF; font-size: medium; height: 28px;" id="l1" 
                               runat="server">View Message </li>

Comment: yes. i am using the .net with c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the javascript function to linkbutton and it will show popup on click

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lnk" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowPopUp();">
```

if you have linkbutton as id you can use jquery to bind script

```
$('#linkbutton').click(ShowPopUp);
```

if you have linkbutton as class you can use jquery to bind script

```
$('.linkbutton').click(ShowPopUp);  


function ShowPopUp(){
  TINY.box.show({
  iframe:'User_News.aspx',
  boxid:'frameless',
  width:250,
  height:250,
  fixed:false,
  maskid:'bluemask',
  maskopacity:40,
  closejs:function(){closeJS()}
  });
}
```

Comment: On which statement you get error and what is the error? Are you using asp.net ?

Comment: when i am writing this code in Script Function. and javascript function not work.

Comment: On which statement you get error and what is the error? Are you using asp.net ?

Comment: yes sir. i am using c#.and when i call that function it does not work.

Comment: c# does not mean that you are using asp.net. I want to know if you are using asp.net ?

Comment: yes sir. i am using the asp.net. and for more info. to you that when i click on link button  the code which you have suggest to me to write inside the function in not work. please tell me and it not call that jquery function.

Comment: Do you know how to debug javascript? and what browser you have?

Comment: i am use Alert("xxxx") and i use Google Chrome.

Comment: This is my answer to show how to debug please debug and tell me exact error you getting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573819/debug-javascript-in-asp-net/10573958#10573958

Comment: now, some changes i made and it looks like o.k. but also one problem that when click on linkbutton it display pop up sometime only for few seconds then after it goes back. it comes sometime only not for all time when i click on linkbutton.

Comment: You need to close popup to show it again because sometime it is minimized. Also try return fasle; from ShowPopUp() function and tell me what happens

Comment: solved it brother and Thanks for Your suggestion and Chat with me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

include jquery library - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Considering `Linkbutton` as classname add this in Script tag -

```
$(function(){
  $('.Linkbutton').on('click', function(){
    $('#frameless').show();
  });
});
```