# Using Jquery to add items in Listbox from Textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

I am stuck somewhere using jquery to append the list box from a text box.

here is my jquery

```
  $("#btnAddSvc").click(function () {
        var svc = $("#<%= txtServiceName.ClientID %>").val();  //Its Let you know the textbox's value   
        svc.appendTo("#<%=lstSvcName.ClientID %>");
    });
```

I am using asp.net (c#) to develop my code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddSvc" runat="server" Text=">>" Font-Size="Medium" />
<asp:ListBox ID="lstSvcName" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" ToolTip="Selected Service Names"
                Width="169px"></asp:ListBox>
```

can someone please help as i am not able to get the values in list box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jQuery selector $() is missing for `"#<%=lstSvcName.ClientID %>"` so you will get `id` of lstSvcName instead of `object`.

I also changed the append statement as it does not have correct syntax.

```
"#<%=lstSvcName.ClientID %>"
```

would be

```
$("#<%=lstSvcName.ClientID %>")
```

Your code will become

```
$("#<%= btnAddSvc.ClientID %>").click(function () {
      var svc = $("#<%= txtServiceName.ClientID %>").val();  //Its Let you know the textbox's value   
      $("#<%=lstSvcName.ClientID %>").append('<option value="'+svc+'">item '+svc+'</option>');
      return false;
});
```

**EDIT [ More functionality requested by OP for unique items in ListBox and clearing TextBox]**

```
$("#<%= btnAddSvc.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    var txt = $("#<%= txtServiceName.ClientID %>");
    var svc = $(txt).val();  //Its Let you know the textbox's value   
    var lst = $("#<%=lstSvcName.ClientID %>");
    var options = $("#<%=lstSvcName.ClientID %> option");
    var alreadyExist = false;
    $(options).each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == svc) {
            alert("Item alread exists");
            alreadyExist = true;
            return;
        }
        txt.val("");
        // alert($(this).val());
    });
    if(!alreadyExist)
            $(lst).append('<option value="' + svc + '">' + svc + '</option>');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Try it now, you had wrong syntax for adding item in listbox, check it now

Comment: Surprisigly this is also not working :( why you have included 5</option> what 5 means here

Comment: It was typing mistake and I have already removed it, let me check why its not working

Comment: Its working, I do not know why not working on your side. Have you included jquery file? and placed this script at right place. Do some debugging it should work. Also take latest code from answer you may not have latest.

Comment: Here is my answer for debugging javascript that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573819/debug-javascript-in-asp-net/10573958#10573958

Comment: Thanks a lot adil for your help i think i might have missed something but same code from raaghav started working for me :)

Comment: Your are welcome, I found what was missing on your side, give it a try now and get updated code from answer.

Comment: Yes its working now :) I am newbie to the world of jquery srry for the trobuble but can i ask ur help in promting user that value already exist i selection list and also clear the text box

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13508/discussion-between-pratik-gupta-and-adil)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using jquery manipulating the DOM but... **Now there's a more elegant way to do it: an object-oriented way (using a MVVM - Model View ViewModel), using [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)**

[Knockoutjs Nuget Package](https://nuget.org/packages/knockoutjs)

You create a binding to your list just adding `data-bind="options: elements"` to your list, and you are always working with objects, never with DOM elements, in this example I have a string array but you can create custom objects and bind them using just a little variation in the syntax

The way to do it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var model = {
            elements: ko.observableArray(),
            addElement: function () {
                this.elements.push($("#<%= this.newElement.ClientID %>").val());
            }
        };

        ko.applyBindings(model);
    });
</script>


    <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="myListbox" Rows="10" Width="25%" data-bind="options: elements">
    </asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="newElement"></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="button" id="addElement" value="Add element" data-bind="click: addElement" />
```

This is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. This may help you. Change the return value for your convenience.

```
   $('#<%= btnAddSvc.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            $textbox = $('#<%= txtServiceName.ClientID %>');
            $listbox = $('#<%= lstSvcName.ClientID %>');
            $listbox.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', $textbox.val()).text($textbox.val()));
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: This is great thanks for your help : One more help needed how can i avoid the duplicates and also delete the ones on delete keystroke

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I dint come online these days. @PratikGupta , Try something like this to delete  `$('#<%= btnDelete.ClientID %>').click(function() {
        $listBox = $('#<%= lstBox.ClientID %>');
        $selectedItem = $listBox.find('option:selected');
        $selectedItem.remove();
        return false;
    });`

Comment: @PratikGupta , Just try these lines of code to check for duplicate entries. I'm not sure this will work. Try modify some lines and try.                      `$textbox = $('#<%= txtText.ClientID %>');
  for (var i = 0, j = selectObject.options.length; i < j; i++)
        {
  if(selectObject.options[i].value==$textbox.val())           
     {
    alert('This Item already exists');
    e.preventDefault();
           }
        }`