# Regular Expression to avoid HTML tags and empty values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex

I have applied a textbox click validation and wanted to avoid any html tags in text box also the simple < (open tag) and  >(close tag). The below code is working for  but i want to add additional validations also for empty strings and other tags in html. Can some one please help modify the regex for the requirement.

```
function htmlValidation() 
 {
   var re = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;

   if (document.getElementById(’<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>’).value.match(re)){ document.getElementById(’<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>’).value = “”;
          return false;
        }
   return true;
 }
```

**Corrected Code above**

Comment: I don't exactly understand what your requirements are. Do you wan't to allow specific tags, or what behaviour do you exactly want?

Comment: I want to exclude any html tags in the textbox...also the "<" and  ">" should not be allowed

Comment: Why not `[^<>]+` ,and check if it does NOT match this pattern. Excluding the `<>` will also exclude any HTML tags.

Comment: @RoadBump: Works only if we anchor your Regexp at the beginning and end of the test string.

Comment: Although I don't know what exactly you are coding, but in many cases it would be better to let the user correct their input instead of you deleting it. < and > can also be escaped so that they are viewed as literals, not as html operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#<%= btnAdd.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            var txt = $("#<%= txtBox1.ClientID %>");
            var svc = $(txt).val();  //Its Let you know the textbox's value 
            var re = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
            if(txt.val()!=""){
            if (!txt.val().match(re)) {
               //my Operations 
               //goes here
                });
                return false;
            }
            else {
                alert("Invalid Content");
            }
            }
            else {
            alert("Blank value selected");
            }
```

I have used Jquery function to check for regular expresion. This question is a linked question with 
[Using Jquery to add items in Listbox from Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358807/using-jquery-to-add-items-in-listbox-from-textbox)

Now i can mark this as my final answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, I believe you'll have a good hard work if you want to validate such things.

Instead of preventing HTML content in a text box, other solution could be just html entity encode Text property, so `<p>a</p>` would be converted to `&gt;p&lt;a&gt;p&lt;`.

Result of that is you're going to render the HTML "as text" instead of getting it interpreted by Web browser.

Check this MSDN article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I validating the user inputs on client side and there is requirement considering the html tags not allowed as it will hangup the other processes. So i im looking to solve at one click event only. If i get some answers will definelty post here

Comment: @PratikGupta But if you do this way, your processes will work as expected, because you won't have HTML!

Comment: there are many places where i specially don't want any special operators as this will give different meaning to the calculations handled hence i want to filter those things out on front end rather than at server side.

Comment: @PratikGupta I believe that an HTML entity isn't an special character. Elaborate more your case if you want further details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.I think i found the answer in my own question.I have made some mistake in the annotations of the javascript code. But now its validating all the HTML tags also inclosed in <any_tags_here>. I have also check your profile on stack it's really impressive.

Comment: @PratikGupta It's not that impressive, I love keeping in touch with other "techies" :D Why don't you post your solution as an answer to your own question? After some hours you'd be able to mark it as the right one.